# How is the language of a font glyph determined?

Tags: windows, file-format

A glyph holds data such as its name and contour points. But how do you determine where the characters of one language end and another begins? Is there a written standard that says language X starts at index Y and ends at index Z?

In case it matters, I'm referring to `.ttf` & `.otf` font files.

I'm unsure if my question fits in this community and I'm struggling to find another, so if there's one better suited, please let me know.

Any info or documentation on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `But how do you determine where the characters of one language end and another begins?` You don't. Why would one need this?